# extern "C" для шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему я не могу объявить шаблонную функцию с `extern "C"`?

```
extern "C"
template <class>
void foo();

int main() {}
```

Comment: потому что в Си нету шаблонов

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch и что? это же с++

Comment: нет... Вы понимаете зачем нужен extern "C"?

Comment: может просто человек хочет экспортить шаблоны?:)

Comment: шаблон функции не является функцией

Comment: Зачем вы используете `extern "C"`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat чтобы указать linkage

Comment: Ну хорошо, а зачем вам сишная linkage на шаблонной функции? Из C ведь вы ее все равно не вызовете.

Comment: вызвать то можно, но нужно, что бы функция была как минимум инстанциирована. А без этого никак. Плюс придется угадать полное имя. Но даже учитывая это, компилятор все равно не даст собрать конкретно этот код

Comment: @KoVadim как вызвать?

Comment: самый простой способ - напишите функцию-обертку, которая будет вызывать шаблонную функцию. И всех то делов

Comment: По одной обертке на каждый набор шаблонных аргументов, который вам нужен, типа `foo_int`, `foo_float`.

Comment: `extern "C"` нужен чтобы отключить плюсовый `name mangling`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что

> The extern specifier is only allowed in the declarations of variables
> and functions (except class members or function parameters).

А шаблон не является ни функцией, ни переменной.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration